# Unable to install node.js package 'scrypt' using npm on windows

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

Installing `scrypt` using `npm` on windows is giving following error. 
The build is failing due to `node-gyp`

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From github documentation `node-Gyp` is listed as pre-requisite as it is required to build `scrypt`. Make it sure to install `node-Gyp`

using `npm install -g node-gyp`

For successfull working of this plugin you will also need to install all the required tools and configurations using Microsoft's [windows-build-tools](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools)

using `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`
from an elevated PowerShell or CMD.exe (run as Administrator).
for other options and alternatives follow `node-gyp` [documentation](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation)

Before installing `scrypt`
Follow installation instructions given [at github](https://github.com/barrysteyn/node-scrypt#installation-instructions)

Answer (score 3):

**For NodeJS 10.5.0 and higher**

My answer could be a little bit out of topic, but I encountered a similar error with the installation of the [`scrypt`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scrypt) library for **NodeJS v12**: during the compilation of the C/C++ modules with `node-gyp` a lot of compiling warnings and errors appear.

Though, there is an elegant solution.

Since version **10.5.0** NodeJS has a [`crypto.scrypt(...)`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_scrypt_password_salt_keylen_options_callback) function, which (with several other functions from `crypto` module) could cover almost all real use-cases.

So, a decent solution could sound like: *Remove [`scrypt`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scrypt)-package from your code and use the appropriate functions from the `crypto`-native module*.

> *Sadly, but in most cases it is not the best solution for a real business*

Answer (score 1):

first you need to install `windows-build-tools`

run this command first

`> npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`